# Finding a matrix A if given solutions of $xA = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I don't understand a step in a solution of the following problem:

Let $A\in Mat_{4x3}(\mathbb{R})$ and suppose all solutions of the equation $xA= 0$ are linear combinations of $x_1= (1,1,1,0)$ and $x_2= (−2,−1,0,1)$. Find its reduced column echelon form and the dimensions of the subspaces ker($T_A$) and im($T_A$).

**Solution** Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent we have that dim(ker($T_A$)) = 2, hence $rank(A) = 4−2 = 2$. Denote with $a_{ij}$ the entry of the matrix A at row i and column j. Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions it must hold that:

$$a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}=0$$
$$a_{12}+a_{22}+a_{32}=0$$
$$a_{13}+a_{23}+a_{33}=0$$
$$-2a_{11}-a_{21}+a_{41}=0$$
$$-2a_{12}-a_{22}+a_{42}=0$$
$$-2a_{13}-a_{23}+a_{43}=0$$
From this, we can compute the reduced echelon form given by:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
     -1 & -1 & 0 \\
     -2 & -1 & 0 \end{array} \right]
\end{equation*}
Now, it's not clear to me how we obtain this matrix from the equations above.
How do we do this?

Comment: $x_2\mathbf A\ne0$. The last row should be $(2,1,0)$ to satisfy the condition that $x_2=(-2,-1,0,1)$ is a solution.